# PFFacebookUtils not logging in

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to log in and save a user to Parse using PFFacebookUtils. Note, I am using the FBSDKLoginButton, and I do NOT want to use the PFLoginViewController, I need a much more custom login. Here is my code:

```
  func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result1: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if error == nil {
      // this block of code is reached fine.


        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], block: { (user, error2) -> Void in
           // both error2 and user both print out to nil here
            print(error2)
            print(user)

            if let newUser = user {
                // inside this block of code is never reached

            }

        })
    }
}
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: give more details about the problems you are facing. Some log would be helpful.

Comment: What is the problem? It's not clear from your question.